# How can I go dynamically heading to heading description?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to go to heading when a user click on heading in table of content. This is dynamically like this in image:
[image]

Here is my code. I get all heading from description.

```
$headingText = [];
    $headingtag = 'h2';
    preg_match_all( '|<'.$headingtag.'>(.*)</'.$headingtag.'>|iU', $les, $headings );
    foreach($headings[0] as $headh2val)
    {
        $headingText[].=$headh2val;
    }
```

I only need to go on click to that heading. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean an anchor link to move the page to that heading?

Comment: yes exactly i want this but dynamically

Comment: So the link can be like this `<a href="#myanchorlink">Link</a>` and then you could add an id to the h2 tag (or create a new div) `<h2 id="myanchorlink">`. When clicked it will move the page to that heading.

Comment: Does this help you?

Comment: yes its helpfull

Comment: I've added an answer, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Create an Anchor link**

Example link:

Use **#** then any name you like in the href.

```
<a href="#myanchorlink">Link</a>
```

Example target:

```
<h2 id="myanchorlink">

or

<div id="myanchorlink"></div>
```

When the link is clicked the page will move to that anchor link id.